# Game programming pattern in LibGDX

Tags: design-patterns, libgdx

What modelling type (or a pattern) is best for programming a platformer in libgdx? I was reading a book "LibGDX Game development" but someone told me that Renderer/Controller pattern is not the best way to model a platformer... Any suggs?

Comment: By the way, have a look at this [great book](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/). You will find many useful things and tricks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MVC is pretty much standard way for game development.
I have used it many times in different projects, even in not game oriented but simply apps.

You can read about it more here.
It should be useful.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller